# Solana smart contract toolkit not working on Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: solana-program

Under what conditions will the smart contract compiler work? Using Hello world contract example:

When using the latest Solana toolkit on Ubuntu 20 I get the error:
root@x:~/solana/app# cargo-build-bpf
/root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/rustc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-f767167903553d17.so) /root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/rustc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version` GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-f767167903553d17.so)
/root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/rustc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/../lib/libstd-cb89995d7fb7a86f.so)
root@x:~/solana/app#

On Windows it is:

D:\Source\solana_stuff\app>cargo build-sbf
[2024-03-14T07:27:29.268246800Z INFO  cargo_build_sbf] Solana SDK: \?\C:\Users\chris.local\share\solana\install\releases\1.18.1\solana-release\bin\sdk\sbf
[2024-03-14T07:27:29.268963900Z INFO  cargo_build_sbf] spawn: "rustup" toolchain list -v
[2024-03-14T07:27:29.289406600Z INFO  cargo_build_sbf] spawn: "rustup" toolchain uninstall solana
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
[2024-03-14T07:27:29.307238300Z INFO  cargo_build_sbf] spawn: "rustup" toolchain link solana \?\C:\Users\chris.local\share\solana\install\releases\1.18.1\solana-release\bin\sdk\sbf\dependencies\platform-tools\rust
[2024-03-14T07:27:29.324952100Z INFO  cargo_build_sbf] spawn: "cargo" +solana build --release --target sbf-solana-solana
error: no such command: `+solana`

```
    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

D:\Source\solana_stuff\app>

On Windows, my rust installation of v1.76 is working fine.

If I run cargo-build-sbf instead I get:
Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.78
Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.12
Compiling version_check v0.9.4
Compiling semver v1.0.22
Compiling typenum v1.17.0
Compiling syn v1.0.109
Compiling serde v1.0.197
Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
Compiling jobserver v0.1.28
Compiling hashbrown v0.14.3
Compiling equivalent v1.0.1
Compiling feature-probe v0.1.1
Compiling toml_datetime v0.6.5
Compiling winnow v0.5.40
Compiling thiserror v1.0.57
Compiling cfg_aliases v0.1.1
Compiling rustversion v1.0.14
Compiling once_cell v1.19.0
Compiling serde_json v1.0.114
Compiling itoa v1.0.10
Compiling arrayvec v0.7.4
Compiling ryu v1.0.17
Compiling either v1.10.0
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `compiler_builtins`

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Sized` in this scope
--> C:\Users\x.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\equivalent-1.0.1\src\lib.rs:77:26
|
77 | pub trait Equivalent<K: ?Sized> {
|                          ^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Sized` in this scope
--> C:\Users\x.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\equivalent-1.0.1\src\lib.rs:82:10
|
82 | impl<Q: ?Sized, K: ?Sized> Equivalent for Q
|          ^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Sized` in this scope
--> C:\Users\x.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15

It can't seem to find even the standard library.

HOME env variable is set to windows user directory